# Infinite dimensional hilbert space & compactness

Tags: general-topology, hilbert-spaces

I got a trouble for solving my home work. I have to prove the following

If $H$ is infinite dimesional hilbert space, then specify a closed unit ball in $H$ is compact or not.

First I though since $H & is metric space, it surely be compact. But I cannot prove this.

I want to know some general way to prove a set is compact or not compact.

Using definition, it might be hard I think. Because we have to consider all open cover or collection of closed sets.

Is there a useful theorem or proposition  to prove compactness? And if possible,  can I get some hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not compact.  A simple way is to use the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem which says that in any metric space, a set $A$ is compact iff every sequence in $A$ has a subsequence that converges in $A$. Consider an orthonormal sequence $\{e_i\}$, compute the distance between $e_i$ and $e_j$, and verify that the sequence has no convergent subsequence.

Your comment "First I though since $H$ is metric space, it surely be compact." suggests a common but serious misconception.  You are probably thinking of the Heine-Borel theorem which says that a closed bounded subset **of Euclidean space** is compact.  This theorem is **not true** in arbitrary metric spaces, and "compact" is **definitely not** a synonym for "closed and bounded".

Comment: Thank you. You correct my misunderstanding about compacrtness. Then the unit ball is not totally bounded right?

Comment: @user277793: Correct.  The orthonormal sequence can also be used to show the ball is not totally bounded (for sufficiently small $r$, any ball of radius $r$ can contain at most one vector from the orthonormal sequence).